# using perform selector with a BOOL parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a function which accepts a `NSString*` parameter and a `BOOL` type parameter:

```
-(void)getIdByName:(NSString*)name shouldAsk:(BOOL)should {
 // I see this log "should = -24", why -24?
 NSLog(@"should = %d", should);
 ...
}
```

I want to call above function by using `performSelector:withObject:withObject:` .

I first gather the parameters(arguments) in a `NSArray` :

```
// 1st parameter is string "abc", 2nd parameter is boolean NO
NSArray * args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"abc", @NO, nil];
```

I call function:

```
[self executeFunc:@selector(getIdByName:shouldAsk:) withArgs:args];
```

where the `executeFunc:withArgs:` looks like this:

```
// This is a general function
-(void)executeFunc:(SEL)selector withArgs:(NSArray*)args {
 ...
 // I see this log prints "2nd arg is 0",which looks correct.
 NSLog(@"2nd arg is %d", [args objectAtIndex:1]);
 [obj performSelector:selector
                      withObject:[args objectAtIndex:0]
                      withObject:[args objectAtIndex:1]];
}
```

When I run above `executeFunc:` function, I see log in it:

```
 2nd arg is 0
```

so the boolean is @NO, that's fine.

But in the function under performing, the log shows:

```
should = -24
```

the boolean parameter has value `-24`, why? How to make it work with correct boolean variable passing into the function under performing?

**==== UPDATE ===**

I also tried to refactor my **general** function to use `NSInvocation` way:

```
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:[obj methodSignatureForSelector:aSelector]];
[invocation setSelector:aSelector];
[invocation setTarget:obj];
for (int i = 0; i < [arguments count]; i++) {
    // compiler error: Cannot take the address of rvalue of type 'id'
    [invocation setArgument:&([arguments objectAtIndex:i]) atIndex:2+i];
}
```

It doesn't work in my scenario. So, I don't think my question duplicates with the question @Sulthan marked.

Comment: `performSelector` won't work with primitive values. Use `NSInvocation`.

Comment: It is not primative, I already wrapped it as an object by `@NO`, primitive is `NO`

Comment: What matters is the declaration of the method, which takes a primitive `BOOL`, not a `NSNumber`.

Comment: @Sulthan, OK...then, how can I make it work without changing the function declaration? Or any workaround?

Comment: @Sulthan, please check my update, I don't think my question duplicates with the question you marked. Because I am using a general function, which can accept any type of argument.

Comment: You must declare the parameters in the called method as objects – as the method name *with**Object*** implies – even if you pass the array as a single parameter, the boolean value is always an `NSNumber` object. A workaround is a protocol/delegate solution which allows methods with non-object parameters. And you have to print the value in `executeFunc` with the `%@` specifier, since it's an **object**.

Comment: Even with your updates, the question is still the same and the answer is `NSInvocation`. It will just be more difficult to create an instance of `NSInvocation`. However, that's just a workaround. With a good architecture you don't need generic functions with generic arguments. There are delegates and closures which can achieve more and better.

Comment: @Sulthan, can you provide a example of how to use delegates/closure to achieve it?

Comment: Yes, if you show us the real use case. Why do you want to call a method through `performSelector` in the first place?

Comment: Make your life a lot, lot easier by using dispatch_after. There's tons of documentation on Apple's site. Or just use Xcode with code completion.